# There is no StackTrace in unhandled exception

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to create crash reporting. For that I'd like to catch all unhandled exceptions and send info about them with mail. 
I've created unhandled exceptions handler like this:

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
        // the code which particularly works
};
```

When is unhandled exception under debugging, it stops in the file App.g.i.cs.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

And there is value in e.Exception.StackTrace. But in my handler StackTrace member is null. Why ?

Comment: Enable Just My Code.